# Network Error on ajax call POST Method with Headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

Hi I am trying an ajax call with post method as below on executing it goes to the error part and returns me "Network Error" or "Error". But i have tried some online tools like Advanced Rest client and Request maker(http://requestmaker.com/) In this I get the json in return and executes successfully so can any one help me in resolving this issue

```
  var headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ZDVhY2Y5NzktYWIxNy00NTk5LWFkOTMtYmZmYzRiZmJlZmY1OjIyYWU3M2IxLWM2NjctNGIxNS1iZmRhLTFlZGNiMDQ0OGNhYw== ',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};

var port = 443;
var url = 'https://api.accuratebackground.com/v3/candidate/';
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: headers,
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify({
        firstname: "hello",
        lastname: "world",
        phone: "206-555-1213",
        dateofbirth: "1972-05-25",
        ssn: "531-90-1991",
        email: "hello@physics.org"
    }),

    success: function(data) {

    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {

        alert(status);

    }
});
```

Comment: there is a space between = and the rest of the base64 encoded stuff, maybe thats the issue.

The data field takes a json object, not a json string

Comment: I tried this but i am getting the same Network Error

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

you have some errors in your code:
1/ an extra comma after error: {}
2/ an extra **}** at the end of your script

after that the request was made but the server responded with 500 error code and this long message XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.accuratebackground.com/v3/candidate/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500. 
so i made some changes in the request header and the result was 401 instead of 500 so that means i am not allowed to access this resource you may need a token access or api key or thing else to authenticate.

Comment: Can You able to share the change you did because i already tried that too in script as well as webconfig

Comment: i just removed headers: headers and put Authorization: 'Basic ZDVhY2Y5NzktYWIxNy00NTk5LWFkOTMtYmZmYzRiZmJlZmY1OjIyYWU3M2IxLWM2NjctNGIxNS1iZmRhLTFlZGNiMDQ0OGNhYw == ',

Comment: Can you please check the following fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/yqg5ff3t/1/) this goes error part and returns me "error". I have made the changes as said by you

Comment: the same error 401, you can see the error log in the javascript console (to open it hit f12 or fn + f12 in your browser) you can also see in network section what the server responded to that request